# teleportation circuit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

Can someone explain me why if I enter the state $|0\rangle$ in $a$, $b$ and $c$ I will read at the exit $x=y=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and $z=|0\rangle$ in the following system
[image: System]
?

Note that the left is the controlled-not operator where $a$ is the control, and the other operators are given by

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we start off with the system in the $|0\rangle |0\rangle|0\rangle$, after the $L$ operator. The second qubit transforms as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle) = |+\rangle$$

Where $|\pm\rangle$ is defined as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle \pm |1\rangle)$. So we now have our system in the state $|0\rangle|+\rangle|0\rangle$. We now have a controlled NOT gate which entangles the second and third qubit:

$$|0\rangle|+\rangle|0\rangle\mapsto |0\rangle\left(\frac{|00\rangle+|11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

The next controlled NOT gate has no effect as the first qubit is in state $|0\rangle$. There is then an $R$ gate on the first qubit, giving us:

$$|0\rangle\left(\frac{|00\rangle+|11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\mapsto|-\rangle\left(\frac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

There is then a controlled-NOT gate on the second two qubits and an $S$ gate applied to the first. Thus our state becomes:

$$|-\rangle\left(\frac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\mapsto |-\rangle|+\rangle|0\rangle$$

We then have a controlled-NOT gate from the third to the first qubit, which has no effect because the third qubit is in state $|0\rangle$.

There is then an $S$ gate on the first qubit, which acts to give:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}i & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}i \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$

And simultaneously there's a $T$ gate applied to the third qubit:

$$|-\rangle|+\rangle|0\rangle \mapsto -\left(\frac{i|0\rangle -|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)|+\rangle|0\rangle$$

There is then a controlled-NOT gate that again has no effect. So we have three separate qubits, the first of mine differs from yours.

It's kind of useful to note that given other inputs a so-called "Bell State" can be produced, which can then be used for [Quantum Teleportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) between Alice and Bob if each only has local access to one of the qubits and a classical line of communication.

Comment: hello and thank you very much for your answer. I can't vote you up because I don't have sufficient punctuation in my account. The result is from the following article: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9605035